# Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently changed my mac osx into ubuntu purely for the sake of installing ROS. I updated my ubuntu system to the latest ubuntu bionic beaver version(allegedly called 18.04 LTS). I started to install ROS Kinetic Kame by following the instruction provided by the official ROS website. When I typed in

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

I received

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

I would like to know the reason. Was it because of the latest version of ubuntu ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278343/unable-to-locate-package-ros-kinetic-desktop-full/) by [5817](https://answers.ros.org/users/33060/5817/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-12-29

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I would like to know the reason. Was it because of the latest version of ubuntu ?

Yes. Kinetic is only supported on Ubuntu 15.10 and 16.04, see [REP-3 - Platforms by Distribution: Kinetic Kame (May 2016 - May 2021)](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0003.html#kinetic-kame-may-2016-may-2021).

> I updated my ubuntu system to the latest ubuntu bionic beaver version(allegedly called 18.04 LTS).

There is currently no official support for any ROS version on Bionic Beaver.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-12-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is apparently no offical version for Bionic yet, which makes sense at is not even in a beta stage yet.
However it seems that some version of ROS is now directly available from the official Ubuntu repo. You can install for instance `sudo apt-get install ros-desktop-full` (without version string indigo/kinetic in the package name)

```
$ apt-cache madison ros-desktop-full
ros-desktop-full |  1.8 | http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe amd64 Packages
ros-desktop-full |  1.8 | http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/universe i386 Packages
```

If someone has more information about the rationale and further plans for that integration and its implications on the deployment of the different ROS releases I would be thankful.

---

Originally posted by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) with karma: 152 on 2018-01-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-01**:
There are some packages in upstream Debian, and thus by extension in Ubuntu. You could use those, but please be aware of the consequences: [wiki/UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2018-01-01**:
Thanks for the pointer. Doesn't sound too convincing to me and looks a bit experimental. Do you have further experience with this distribution?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-02**:
No, I don't. I applaud the effort of getting ROS packaged for a mainstream distribution like this, but seeing as ROS is always very much in development (even the core) I'm not convinced the LTS characteristics of a typical Debian distro/release are compatible with the way ROS works.

**Comment by [SR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14071/sr/) on 2018-01-02**:
Thx, agreed.